# warning: deleting array "......." munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Command terminated by signal 6

Tags: c++, class, oop, destructor

Currently, I was trying to learn and use the destructor function in this program. I have created a class named Student which can take Roll number, name and marks for 3 subjects which I stored it in an array. I cannot delete the array created to store the marks of the student...

I was getting an error/warning message...

> In destructor ‘Student::~Student()’: :65:14: warning: deleting array
> ‘((Student*)this)->Student::marks’    65 |     delete[] marks;
> |              ^~~~~ munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Command terminated by signal 6

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//This class gets rollNo, name, marks for 3 subjects....
class Student
{
    private:
        int rollNumber;
        string name;
        int marks[3];
        
    public:
        
        void setRollnumber(int roll)
        {
            rollNumber = roll;
        }
        
        void setName(string name)
        {
            this->name = name;
        }
        
        void setMarks(int marks1, int marks2, int marks3)
        {
            this -> marks[0] = marks1;
            this -> marks[1] = marks2;
            this -> marks[2] = marks3;
        }
        
        int totalMarks();
        
        char grade(int totalMarks, int maxMarks);
        
        ~Student();
        
};
//Finds the total marks...
int Student :: totalMarks()
{
    int total = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        total += marks[i];
    }
    
    return total;
    
}
//Returns the grade...
char Student :: grade(int totalMarks, int maxMarks)
{
    float percent = ((float)totalMarks / (float)maxMarks) * 100;
    
    char grade;
    grade = percent >= 90 ? 'A' : (percent >= 75) ? 'B' : (percent >= 50) ? 'C' : 'F';
    
    return grade;
}

//Destructor....
Student :: ~Student()
{
    delete &rollNumber;
    delete &name;
    delete[] marks; 
}

int main(){
    
    Student bee;
    
    bee.setRollnumber(50);
    bee.setName("Bee");
    bee.setMarks(90, 80, 70);
    
    int total_marks_scored = bee.totalMarks();
    
    cout<<"Total Marks    : "<<total_marks_scored<<endl;
    cout<<"Grade Obtained : "<<bee.grade(total_marks_scored, 300);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: You did not `new` them. Why do you `delete` them?

Answer (score 0):

[delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/) is used to deallocate memory that was dynamically allocated on the heap with a call to [new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/).  Likewise with [delete[]](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/)and [new[]](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/).

You are not dynamically allocating any memory so you do not need to deallocate it.  You do not need the destructor in this case.

You also don't use the & with the delete calls.

If you want to keep the destructor because you say you are learning then you need to allocate the memory for your class members with calls to new, but the members would then need to be pointers...

```
private:
        int* rollNumber;
        string* name;
        int* marks;
```

and allocate memory for them with new, preferably in a constructor.

```
Student::Student() : 
    rollNumber(new int(0)),
    name(new string("")),
    marks(new int[3]))
{}
```